# Finding the matrix of a linear transformation in a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $C$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. $$C = \{c_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \cr 2 \cr 3 \end{bmatrix}, c_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \cr 1 \cr -1 \end{bmatrix}, c_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \cr 0 \cr 1 \end{bmatrix}\}$$

L is a linear transformation satisfying $$L(c_1)=c_1+c_2+c_3\\ L(c_2)=-3c_1+2c_2 \\ L(c_3)=c_1+c_2+c_3$$

I'm trying to find the matrix of $L$ with respect to $C$. So my first thought is that the columns of $L$ are $\begin{bmatrix} L(c_1) 
L(c_2) L(c_3) \end{bmatrix}$. So now I calculate and I get, and so on that I find L to be $$L = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -3 & 1 \\ 3 & -4 & 3 \\ 3 & -11 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

Which I found by adding up and scaling the vectors in C. Is this right? Or am I instead looking for something like $$L = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -3 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ by simply taking the numbers before each $c$ in that description of $L$ above? Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix representation for $L$ respect to the ordered base $C=\{c_1,c_2,c_3\}$ of ${\bf R}^3$ is given by

$$[L]_{C}^{C}:=\begin{pmatrix} \uparrow&\uparrow&\uparrow\\ [L(c_1)]_{C}&[L(c_2)]_{C}&[L(c_3)]_{C}\\\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow \end{pmatrix}\in M_{3\times 3}({\bf R})$$where each column $[T(c_j)]_{C}$ is the coordinate respect to the ordered base $C$.

In your case you know directly $L(c_1),L(c_2)$ and $L(c_3)$ and noticing  for example that $L(c_1)=1\cdot c_1+1\cdot c_2+1\cdot c_3$, thus by definition of coordinates we have $$[L(c_1)]_{C}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\\end{pmatrix}.$$
Similarly with the other coordinates and we have the matrix representation for $L$ respect to $C$ is given by

$$[L]_{C}^{C}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-3&1\\1&2&1\\1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: That makes perfect sense that the columns are L(c) with respect to C, thank you so much

Comment: It is a pleasure to help, successes in your studies.